# Deployment issue with a specific error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I treat/fix this error Command "yarn run build" exited with 1 while trying to deploy my project/website. I tried searching for the problem but I couldn’t get it

I’ve tried to check my repository but I couldn’t get where the issue is from. Please help

Comment: There should be other parts of the error that gives away what's wrong exactly. Edit your question and post the whole error messages that you get in the terminal

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.